# EXACT number of intersection points of two algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-curves, intersection-theory

As the picture shows[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9VLU.png)(the paper's link is in [1](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/apexprod/rws_etd/send_file/send?accession=oberlin1385137385&disposition=inline)),it seems that I can use tools including Bezout's theorem to solve the EXACT number of intersection between two algebraic curves(F(x,y) is of degree two and with variables x and y.G(x,y) is of degree four and with variables x,y ).

But so far I don't see it.
So please help me if you have any thought on this,thanks!

Comment: It depends on whether you take into account the multiplicities of intersection or not. Assuming you just want the cardinality of the set-theoretic intersection, this is done in the following nicely written paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0361 This has been implemented in Magma: https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1386#15457 (you can use Magma with the online calculator).

Comment: Also, what is your field $k$? Do you mean the $k$-rational points? Do you include the points at infinity?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thanks for your help!To be simple I just want to know how many common points do Three ellipses have on the R^2 plane.And that's  equivalent to how many common points do two algebraic curves have.I would read the paper  through and try Magma as soon as possible after I finish my homework before the deadline.Thanks again!

Comment: This is not equivalent: Bézout's theorem only gives the number of points over the complex numbers, not the reals. To get the number of real intersection points, you need to use Hilmar-Smyth and count the number of real embeddings of the number fields that appear.